# What does it mean to "include the corresponding worker script (app-indexeddb-mirror-worker.js) among your deployable files"?

Tags: polymer

In the documentation for app-indexeddb-mirror at https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/app-storage?active=app-indexeddb-mirror there is a section I've copied below. I think I'm running into an error because the indicated file isn't loading, but I'm not sure how to fix the issue. Do I add a reference in staticFileGlobs in sw-precache-config.js or somewhere else?

> In order to ensure that operations on IndexedDB block the main browser thread as little as possible, app-indexeddb-mirror relies on a WebWorker to operate on its corresponding IndexedDB database. If you are vulcanizing or otherwise combining your source files before your app is deployed, make sure that you include the corresponding worker script (app-indexeddb-mirror-worker.js) among your deployable files. You can configure the path to the worker script with the worker-url attribute.

The error I'm getting:

> GET https://example.com/src/common-worker-scope.js?https://example.com/bower_components/app-storage/app-indexeddb-mirror/app-indexeddb-mirror-worker.js net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED

Comment: I'm having troubles integrating Firebase and app-indexeddb-mirror. I've written a question as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39048219/firebase-and-app-indexeddb-mirror-integration-not-working. In my opinion the app-indexeddb-mirror-workier.js is auto managed by the element as it's located in bower_components\app-storage\app-indexeddb-mirror.